# Get PDF by taking the derivative of CDF

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

Question: Let $Y= 1-X$. Find its cumulative distribution function and its density, in terms of $F_X$ and $f_X$

My way to do:

$$F_{Y}(y)=P(1-X<y)=P(X>1-y)\\=1-P(X\le1-y)\\=1-F_X(1-y) \\=1-\lim \limits_{x \to 1-y} F_X(x)$$

$$F_{Y}(y)=1-\lim \limits_{x \to 1-y} F_X(x)$$

Then, I want to find PDF by $\frac{d(F_{Y}(y))}{dy}$.

Is PDF just $-\lim \limits_{x \to 1-y}f_X(x)$ ? If wrong, how can I get that.

Comment: Apart from the strange notation $F_x(x)$, I am puzzled: why write a limit if the CDF is continuous? How do you differentiate if it's not? (answer to your question: obviously no, a PDF is positive...)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Edited.

Comment: I simplified the notation a little bit. But my comment remains: why write a limit, and how do you believe $f_Y$ can be negative? Notice that when you differentiate $1-F_X(1-y)$ w.r.t. $y$, you don't get $-f_X(1-y)$. You are failing on the derivative of a composition of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F_Y(y)=P(1-X\leq y)=P(X\geq1-y)=1-P(X<1-y)=1-P(X\leq1-y)=$$$$1-F_X(1-y)\tag1$$where the $4$-th equality is implied by the fact that $F_X$ is continuous.

This is enough concerning CDF: $F_Y$ is expressed by means of $F_X$.

If $F_X(x)$ would be differentiable (we don't know) having derivative $f(x)$ then $(1)$ tells us that $F_Y(y)$ is differentiable having derivative $f(1-y)$.

This makes us "suspect" that the function $g(y)=f_X(1-y)$ will serve as PDF of $Y$.

This can be verified by:$$\int_{-\infty}^yf_X(1-z)dz=\int_{1-y}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx=P(X\geq1-y)=P(Y\leq y)$$

Proved is now that: $$f_Y(y)=f_X(1-y)$$

This is enough concerning PDF: $f_Y$ is expressed by means of $f_X$.

Answer (score 1):

You have already obtained  $$F_{Y}(y)=1-F_X(1-y)$$
(However, I am not sure if it is necessary to express the same result using the limit concept)

Here $Y= 1-X$
     $\Rightarrow X=1-Y$
So, $\frac{dx}{dy}=-1$

Now, you can differentiate the c.d.f. of $Y$ with respect to $y$ which yields

$$\frac{d}{dy}F_{Y}(y)=\frac{d}{dx}[1-F_X(1-y)]\frac{dx}{dy}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow f_Y(y)=[-f_X(1-y)](-1)$$
$$\Rightarrow f_Y(y)=f_X(1-y)$$